# Is it safe to use IEnumerable for something that may be enumerated multiple times?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumeration

For example let's say I have the following:

```cs
public class StringTester
{
    IEnumerable<IStringConditional> Conditionals { get; }

    public StringTester(IEnumerable<IStringConditional> conditionals)
    {
        conditionals = Conditionals;
    }

    public bool TestString(string testString)
    {
        foreach (var conditional in Conditionals)
        {
            if (!conditional.Test(testString))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this regarded as safe, or are IEnumerable types only safe for a single enumeration? If not what type would be best to use in a case like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "safe", but this usage is perfectly fine.

Comment: As long as you aren't trying to push / pop to the IEnumerable inside the loop, you should be fine

Comment: I think you need to understand how the `IEnumerable` interface works.

Comment: It depends on the enumeration. Whether or not an enumeration is safe to enumerate more than once is not encoded in the type. Even where safe, it's usually not efficient. If you need to enforce that an enumerable be materialized, you can do so explicitly when the enumerable is passed in (`.ToList()`) or enforced in the contract (`ICollection`). Of course you then also lose the ability to defer enumeration (which may be good or bad depending on the use case).

Comment: does this answer your question? [PossibleMultipleEnumeration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html)

Comment: `IEnumerables` are technically "safe" to enumerate multiple times, but it's often undesirable: enumerating one might require a round-trip to a database, or might invoke a lot of processing (if it was e.g. created using a long chain of Linq methods). It's normally best to avoid enumerating them multiple times, especially if you don't know where they came from. If you're going to store one in a field, you might want to get consumers to pass in something a little more concrete (an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, say), which avoids making an unnecessary copy

Comment: Well with Python, iterators which only ever iterate once aren't uncommon, e.g. something created using yield might only be iterable once. If what is behind IEnumerable is also using a similar setup with yield, will that not cause the same issue?

Comment: @LeviH If you've got an `IEnumerable` created from a method which uses `yield`, then enumerating the `IEnumerable` a second time will effectively start executing the yielding method again, from the start. If the first thing the method does is query a database, for example, then that's going to get queried again

Comment: @canton7 ok that's where my confusion was. In python if I have a method which uses yield, then do foo = yield_method(), then I can only iterate through foo once, once I've done that it's gone and won't 'reset'.

Comment: @LeviH C# is not dissimilar. There's `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`. You use an `IEnumerable<T>` to create an `IEnumerator<T>` (call its `GetEnumerator()` method). The `IEnumerator<T>` is the thing which has a `Current` property and a `MoveNext()` method, and can walk through the `IEnumerable<T>` once in a forwards-only way, without a way to reset it (often). Given an `IEnumerable<T>` though, you can create multiple `IEnumerator<T>`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *undefined* as to whether `IEnumerable<T>` is repeatable in the general case. Often (usually): it is. However, examples exist that either:

- can only *ever* be iterated once (think "data from a socket")
- can be iterated many times, but give completely different data each time (without any corresponding obvious state mutation)

So: in general I wouldn't advise ever iterating it more than once *unless you know the scenario is a repeatable one*. Things like arrays and lists are repeatable (if the data changes, of course, they may change to show those changes).

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe but it might not be optimal. The devil is in the implementation.

`IEnumerable` calls `GetEnumerator()` which returns an `IEnumerator` that implements a `Reset()` function.

How this function is implemented is what might cause some problem. If you're enumerating an array calling `Reset()` simply sets its internal pointer to -1 and it's ready to enumerate again.

If you're enumerating something connected over a network you might have to redo that whole connection process and query the data again which will be longer and sub-optimal when used more than once.